# passing data back to view controller not working (iOS)

Tags: xcode, ios5, delegates

I see there are lots of posts on this topic but none seem to solve my problem.

I have to a view controller with has just a textfield, a navigation bar button (called save) and a number/punctuation keyboard.

[image]

The other view controller has a static table view with 2 rows.

[image]

Workflow: When a user taps on the 1st row in the table, the second view controller appears (this already works).
The user then enters a number and when they tap save, the number typed should be used to set the detail label of the 1st row in the table view.

I have set up my protocols and delegates but something is wrong as the 2nd view controller does not disappear and also detail label never gets updated to reflect this typed number.

I am very stumped. Been through lots of code samples and tried so many things but still no solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is my code for both classes.

1st View (The table view)
.h file (The hourlyRateDetialLabel is the detail label from the table view):

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h
#import "priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController.h"

@interface priceCalculatorSettingsViewController : UITableViewController<SettingsViewControllerDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *hourlyRateDetialLabel;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "priceCalculatorSettingsViewController.h"
#import "priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController.h"

@interface priceCalculatorSettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation priceCalculatorSettingsViewController
@synthesize hourlyRateDetialLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController *vc = [[priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController alloc] init];
vc.settingsViewDelegate = self;
}

- (void) HourlyRateDidSave:(priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController *)controller didSetHourlyRate:(NSString *)rateValue{

    self.hourlyRateDetialLabel.text = rateValue;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

The 2nd Class (The View with the textfield and save button)
.h file

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h

@class priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController;

@protocol SettingsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)HourlyRateDidSave:
(priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController *)controller didSetHourlyRate:(NSString *)rateValue;

@end


@interface priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *setHourlyRate;


@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SettingsViewControllerDelegate> settingsViewDelegate;
- (IBAction)saveHourlyRateValue:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController.h"

@interface priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController{

}
@synthesize setHourlyRate = _setHourlyRate;
@synthesize settingsViewDelegate;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Automatically show the keybaord
    [_setHourlyRate becomeFirstResponder];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setSetHourlyRate:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}


- (IBAction)saveHourlyRateValue:(id)sender {

    [self.settingsViewDelegate HourlyRateDidSave:self didSetHourlyRate:_setHourlyRate.text];

}


@end
```

Comment: Your provided code does not appear to include the creation of a `priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController` or setting its `settingsViewDelegate`. There's no way to determine why you do not see your expected behavior given this sample.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out... I have the creation set as so: `priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController *vc = [[priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController alloc] init];
    vc.settingsViewDelegate = self;` but still not working

Comment: Who is the table view's data source? Usually the table view will update automatically when its data source changes and you call `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: in didSelectRowAtIndexPath how you are presenting vc using navigation controller's pushviewcontroller method  or using [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES]; ?

Comment: I am using a static table so I used a push segue to load the respective view for each row...

Answer (score 0):

The provided code includes:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController *vc = [[priceCalculatorHrRateSettingsViewController alloc] init];
vc.settingsViewDelegate = self;
}
```

This creates a controller when a cell is selected but never presents it and yet the unexpected behavior is described as:

> ...2nd view controller does not disappear...

These seems to be at odds with each other. Without an accurate description of 1. the expected behavior 2. the observed behavior and 3. the actual implementation producing the observed behavior, it is almost impossible for anyone to solve this problem. Please do not ask us all to guess how to help.